# C# 3.5 datagridview column header click does not sorts

Tags: c#, winforms

I have winform there is datagridview control when i click on column header it does not sorts.
Can anyone advice me whats wrong?

Comment: please show us your code snippet?

Comment: nothing special im just bind datagrid like this :  DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
                bs = new BindingSource();
                bs.DataSource = db.GetProducts.ToList();
                dgvInventory.DataSource = bs;

Comment: check this[Post](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/multicolumn_sort.aspx)

Comment: You need a `BindingList` that supports sorting. Google will be your friend here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/1699642/546813

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each column has "SortMode" property in datagridview control.
SortMode Values : Automatic, NotSortable, Programmatic
You could check SortMode property.

Comment: yeah know that there is set automatic at all columns. but i does not works . thanks for replay

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void dataGridView1_ColumnAdded(object sender, DataGridViewColumnEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Column.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
        }
```