# Datagrid Sorting GB,MB,KB,B's

Tags: c#, sorting, datagrid

Ok so i have made an application to get the mailbox sizes from exchange, however i need some help making the sort work well.
I databound the grid with my own class, i used the solution here to make my list sortable: [How to sort databound DataGridView column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699642/how-to-sort-databound-datagridview-column)

but when trying to sort the mailbox sizes it doesnt do it like i want it, please can someone give me some insight on this ? 
Right now on purpose i have split the MB part and the size(double) into 2 different columns.
Any idea is welcom.
[image]

On the screenshot the problem is not visible, however i'd like just the GB on top, however the MB's end up on top cause its easy to have 200MB instead of 200GB in your mailbox.

Comment: Your problem is most likely that whatever `CompareTo` implementation you've come up with is being used on the string "10,8 GB" rather than on the underlying value, so you will be sorting your entries alphabetically. You should set up your UI so that the "GB" is being added by a String Format for the display only, and your sort code is sorting the underlying values numerically.

Comment: So if i understand you correct i should just have the bytevalue (easy to get for me) saved somewhere and have to sort on that ? in that case could you give me an example, i would not know how that would be done

Comment: No, there's no need to duplicate your data. If you want example solutions, you'll have to post your existing code for linking the data to the UI, sorting, and everything else related.

Comment: is it possible i sent it to you by email ? i'd rather not have everyone being able to download it.

Comment: Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). 1. All questions and answers are 100% public on this site. 2. You should be simplifying your code as much as possible (reduce it to its purest form) to illustrate what you are trying to accomplish and where the problem lies. If you have done this correctly, there should be nothing left in your code that you are uncomfortable having publicly available. Finally, remember that you are asking for help, and we are volunteering assistance for free, so you should expect to be doing most of the work yourself.

Comment: Sorry, was simply asking if its possible, here is the download to the source: Thennot >.>

Comment: I'll reiterate: You should be simplifying your code as much as possible (reduce it to its purest form) to illustrate what you are trying to accomplish and where the problem lies. If you simply post a download link to your entire source code, it's unlikely that anyone will have any interest in downloading and going through it - I certainly wouldn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments above i have been able to come up with a way to make this work.
i added an additional value to my class which contains the byte's only, made this a hidden column in the grid.
used the event of headerclick and in here i made it sorting on the hidden column instead of the string column