# Sort Data in GridView in asp

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I have a GridView that is filled with data from a database. I get My data using a mssql function. This is how i am getting my data:

```
private void GetNoLocationScanAddress(GridView grid, int week)
        {
            try
            {
                FunctionDataContext function = new FunctionDataContext();
                List<Fn_GetNoLocationAddressGroupedResult> address = function.Fn_GetNoLocationAddressGrouped("0X", week).ToList();
                grid.DataSource = address;
                grid.DataBind();
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR in GetNoLocationScanAddress() method. Error Message : " + exception.Message);
            }
        }
```

The Problem is i am already sorting the data in my function. I am also using a Switch case to determine what data is selected for viewing.

```
 protected void WeekSelector_OnIndexChanhed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            switch (RadioButtonList.SelectedIndex)
            {
                case 0:
                    GetScanErrorsAddress(Grid, Convert.ToInt32(WeekSelector.SelectedValue));
                    Grid.DataBind();
                    break;

                case 1:
                    GetScanErros(Grid, Convert.ToInt32(WeekSelector.SelectedValue));
                    Grid.DataBind();
                    break;

                case 2:
                    GetNoLocationScanAddress(Grid, Convert.ToInt32(WeekSelector.SelectedValue));
                    Grid.DataBind();
                    break;

                case 3:
                    GetNoLocationScan(Grid, Convert.ToInt32(WeekSelector.SelectedValue));
                    Grid.DataBind();
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Function sql:

```
SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT Request1.RequestID, TrackIT.dbo.Sending.Barcode, TrackIT.dbo.Address_View.AdrID, TrackIT.dbo.Address_View.Name, 
                      TrackIT.dbo.Address_View.Street, TrackIT.dbo.Address_View.HouseNo, TrackIT.dbo.Address_View.Postal, TrackIT.dbo.Address_View.City, 
                      TrackIT.dbo.Address_View.Country, Request1.Latitude +','+  Request1.Longitude AS Location,  Case when(Request1.Latitude<>'')then cast(1 as bit) else cast(0 as bit) end AS showLocation, Request1.ReceivedDate
FROM         (SELECT DISTINCT RequestID, LTRIM([Content]) AS Barcode, Latitude, Longitude, ReceivedDate
                       FROM          dbo.RequestWithLocation
                       WHERE      (Site LIKE @Site) AND ([Content] <> '') AND (AddressID = '0') AND (ReceivedDate > DATEADD(day, -@ReceivedDate, GETDATE()))) AS Request1 INNER JOIN
                      TrackIT.dbo.Sending ON Request1.Barcode = TrackIT.dbo.Sending.Barcode INNER JOIN
                      TrackIT.dbo.Address_View ON TrackIT.dbo.Sending.DeliveryAdrID = TrackIT.dbo.Address_View.AdrID

ORDER BY TrackIT.dbo.Address_View.AdrID
```

Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what your problem is. In which sort order does the data come in, how do you want it to be sorted instead, and how is the current sorting achieved? If I understand correctly, you are sorting in your stored procedure. In that case please provide the source for that SP.

Comment: I am sorting in my SP but the user has to be able to sort by pressing the column header if the user wishes to sort the GridView.

Comment: Please check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699642/how-to-sort-databound-datagridview-column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use - **Linq (OrderBy or OrderByDescending)**, to sort your `List<Fn_GetNoLocationAddressGroupedResult>`.

Eg.

```
address.OrderBy(x => x.Country);            // ascending
address.OrderByDescending(x => x.Country);  // descending
```

Answer (score 1):

From your comments, if the user has to be able to sort the gridview by pressing the column header and if you are using a standard ASP.NET System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView, you can simply "Enable Sorting", in the properties pane by setting "AllowSorting" to true or via the "pop-out" on the top right of the control by checking "Enable Sorting".