# VB BindingSource SupportsSorting is false. Why?

Tags: .net, vb.net, list, sorting, bindingsource

I've been cruising around the interwebs trying to figure this out but I cant.

I have a `BindingSource` to which I `.add` a bunch of `FileInfo`s from `.GetFiles`.

When I step through, the `BindingSource`'s `SupportsSorting` property is `False`. I don't understand why.

I tried setting the `BindingSource.DataSource` to a `BindingList` in stead of adding each `FileInfo` one by one, but then the underlying list is still of type `IList`.

Here's my code:

```
 If Directory.Exists(configPath) Then
            For Each foundFile As FileInfo In New DirectoryInfo(configPath).GetFiles("*.csv", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
                If foundFile.Length >= My.Settings.scanFileSizeThreshold Then

                    scansBindingSource.Add(foundFile)
                End If
            Next
        Else
```

All I want to do is something like this:

```
scansBindingList.Sort = "LastWriteTime Desc"
```

And have the data in a DataGridView sorted by last write time. Is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: If the underlying data is in a `BindingList`, they do not support sorting.  The BindingSource is just a wrapper, so it cannot add capabilities

Comment: [This project](http://blw.sourceforge.net/) may be of some help, or perhaps the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699642/how-to-sort-databound-datagridview-column).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `BindingList` does not support sorting.  As well on MSDN has this for `BindingSource`:

> If the data source is not an IBindingList, the SupportsSorting property always returns false.

You can have NET deliver the files to you in the order of `LastWriteTime` so that you dont have to sort them (and also get rid of the loop):

```
Dim theFiles = New DirectoryInfo(fpath).EnumerateFiles(fmask, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).
            Where(Function(f) f.Length > szMin).
            OrderByDescending(Function(s) s.LastWriteTime)

dgv2.DataSource = New BindingSource(theFiles, Nothing)
```

NET will put the files in order and exclude the files which do not match rather than deliver them to you just to be tested and excluded.  The result is an `IEnumerable` which the binding source can use directly.

If you want to be able to add to a list of these and sort them, use a `List(Of FileInfo)` for storage and sorting and then a `BindingSource` for adding/deleting.

```
Private filesBS As BindingSource
Private FilesList As List(Of FileInfo)
...
FilesList = New DirectoryInfo(...).EnumerateFiles("*.csv", SearchOption.AllDirectories).
               Where(Function(f) f.Length > MinSize).
               OrderByDescending(Function(q) q.LastWriteTime).
               ToList()

filesBS = New BindingSource(FilesList, Nothing)
dgv2.DataSource = filesBS
```

The files query is the same as before, I just added `ToList()`; then use it for the `BindingSource`.  If you add and remove items via the `BindingSource` they will show in the collection and DGV.

```
filesBS.RemoveAt(0)
filesBS.Add(newItem)
```

The dreary part is sorting because it has to be done 'manually' (which is to say the DGV wont /cant do it) and because there are so many properties to `FileInfo`.  One way to sort is to use extension methods as was done in the query:

```
' sort by file size
If fileSortOrder = SortOrder.Ascending Then
    FilesList = FilesList.OrderBy(Function(f) f.Length).ToList()
Else
    FilesList = FilesList.OrderByDescending(Function(f) f.Length).ToList()
End If
filesBS = New BindingSource(FilesList, Nothing)
' ToDo: toggle fileSortOrder like below

dgv2.DataSource = filesBS
```

Note that since the `FilesList` collection is recreated, you need to rebuild the `BindingSource` as well.  You can also use the `Sort` method:

```
FilesList.Sort(AddressOf FileInfoSizeCompare)
dgv2.Refresh()
...
Private fileSortOrder As SortOrder = SortOrder.Ascending
Private Function FileInfoSizeCompare(x As FileInfo, y As FileInfo) As Int32
    Dim sortReverser As Int32 = If(fileSortOrder = SortOrder.Ascending, 1, -1)
    Dim ret As Int32 = 0
    If x.Length < y.Length Then ret = -1
    If x.Length > y.Length Then ret = 1

    Return (ret * sortReverser)
End Function
```

In this case, since the list is not recreated, you just need to refresh the control to redraw the contents.  You will need a different method for each column/property you wish to sort by.  With either approach, if you invoke the methods from the `ColumnHeaderMouseClick` event, it will work like it does when the DGV can sort the `DataSource`.

If I were to use the second version, I might put the Sort methods in a class so that a) I could reuse them and b) to get all that code out of the forms.